# [Firebase]I can not get value from object in controller

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the controller.js

```
$scope.user_extras = $firebaseObject(fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid));
```

I want to get value from object that called beepPlay to do some condition

```
 if($scope.user_extras.beepPlay == "play"){
        //do something
    }else if($scope.user_extras.beepPlay == "stop"){
        //do something
        }
```

but it said

> "Cannot read property 'beepPlay' of undefined"

in .html page I can use `{{user_extras.beepPlay}}` normally
but I want to get beepPlay's value to use in `controller.js`

Comment: Did you wait for $scope.user_extras to be loaded before you checked the beePlay property?

Comment: No I didn't,Can you teach me how to do that please ?

Comment: i try to use $loaded but still doesn't work I don't understand use .